# Error at checking the equality of 2 dates from different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to check if the dates in table1 (I have to add a month) are equal with the ones in table2. The tables are being connected by (id_ap) and I get the error "NOT A GROUP BY EXPRESSION"

table1 (id_ap,year,month) ~ month and year are numbers

table2 (id_ap,data)

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(table1.year, '9999') || TO_CHAR(table1.month, 'FM00') || '01', 'YYYYMMDD'),1)AS "Date table1", table2.data, table2.id_ap
FROM table1 join table2
ON table1.id_ap = table2.id_ap
//Group by table2.data,table1.id_ap    -- I tried both with and without group by, but same error
HAVING ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(table1.year, '9999') || TO_CHAR(table1.month, 'FM00') || '01', 'YYYYMMDD'),1) = table2.data
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
SELECT table2.data, table2.id_ap
FROM table1 JOIN
     table2
     ON table1.id_ap = table2.id_ap AND
        ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(table1.year, '9999') || TO_CHAR(table1.month, 'FM00') || '01', 'YYYYMMDD'), 1) = table2.data
GROUP BY table2.data, table1.id_apgroup;
```

Notes:

- `join` conditions should go in the `on` clause.  Not a `having` clause (especially) and not usually in a `where` clause.
- You only need `table2.data`.  Your `join` condition guarantees that they are the same.
- You *could* put the entire expression in the `group by`.  But why bother?  You have the value in `table2`.

Comment: @Huffepuff . . . That is even better.  The `group by` adds additional overhead.